# E:Malformed entry 57 in list file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, deb

I was trying to install and run "Origin" games. But something went wrong.

The error message was:'error: opening the cache (E:Malformed entry 57 in list file/ect/apt/sources/list /etc/apt/sources.list, E:type'"deb' is not know on line 1 in source list/ect/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list, E:the list of sources could not be read.)'

I don't know how to undo it. And it seems to not let get updates.